# Вывод текста после обработки

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал форму обратной связи с ajax на сайте. В самом скрипте вывод сообщения следующий:

```
if(msg == 'OK') {result = '<div class="notification_ok">Спасибо, Ваше сообщение было отправлено!</div>';}
```

Сообщение выводится, как обычный текст тегах "p". Но как можно сделать, чтобы вывод был как у заголовков, например в "h2"?

Comment: написать в *CSS* стиль для `notification_ok` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="notification_ok" style = 'font-size: 16px;'>
```

ну или напрямую в листах стилей для `class = 'notification_ok'`

```
.notification_ok {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: спасибо Вам, очень помогли!